# problemas de renderização com mapbox com react-map-gl

Tags: map

Estou com um problema no react,onde eu defino o tamanho do mapa, o componente fica no tamanho certinho, os botões de zoom ficam todos nos lugarem certo. mas a imagem e si do mapa começa pequena e no canto, porem quando mexo rapidamente no tamanho da tela, a imagem do mapa vai pro tamanho definido. alguem sabe dizer oq seria isso?

const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
latitude: 0,
longitude: 0,
zoom: 4,
//bearing: 0,
//pitch: 0,
});

<Map
{...viewport}
mapLib={import('mapbox-gl')}
onMove={evt => setViewport(evt.viewState)}
mapboxAccessToken={TOKEN}
style={{position: "relative", width: "100% !important", height: "45rem"}}
mapStyle={map_style}
>
{
plants.map((plant: Plants) =>{
const myPosition = {
lat: Number(plant.plantLat),
lng: Number(plant.plantLon)
}
return (

)
})
}